# How to connect Google Cloud CDN to the Cloud Run for Anthos default setup?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-cdn, google-anthos

Have a **Cloud Run for Anthos** set up with default configuration, **istio-ingress** as a gateway and couple of services. Cannot find any docs on how to connect Cloud CDN with this setup.
Does anybody have some experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud CDN content delivery network works with HTTP(S) load balancing to deliver content to your users[1](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview). As Istio ingress works with Network load balancer instead, so it cannot be used with Cloud CDN.

Alternatively, when you create an Ingress object, the GKE ingress controller creates a Google Cloud HTTP(S) load balancer and configures it according to the information in the Ingress and its associated Services.[2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So am I understanding right that in order to get Cloud CDN connected to the GKE cluster I should not use Cloud Run and set up my GKE cluster manually with appropriate ingress config?

Comment: You can still use Cloud Run with this setup.All you need is to have Cloud CDN with HTTP(S) load balancer to deliver content to your users.